# How to store a multivalued attribute in Firebase Database using Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am making an android for people to share their skills. How do I store their skills in the firebase as each of them will be having a different number of skills.
The attribute I have taken are Name,Email,Mobile Number,Skills.
When I update the skills attribute then the old value is getting replaced by a new value. But I want the new value to be added without losing the old value.

[When save button is clicked then name and number must be saved to firebase and if add skill is clicked then skills must be added to the firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCGEd.png)

This is code for that screenshot Activity. IF Possible can I get all of these attributes in a single json?

```
package com.coginitoamicis.coginitoamicis;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public class Account extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

private EditText accname;
private EditText accnumb;
private EditText accskill;

private Button accsave;
private Button accskilladd;

private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_account);

    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()==null){
        finish();
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class));
    }

    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    accname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.accname);
    accnumb = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.accnumb);
    accsave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.accsave);

    accskill = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.accskill);
    accskilladd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.accskilladd);

    accsave.setOnClickListener(this);
    accskilladd.setOnClickListener(this);
}

private void userdatasave(){

    String name = accname.getText().toString().trim();
    String numb = accnumb.getText().toString().trim();

    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(name)){
        //name is empty
        Toast.makeText(this,"Please Enter your Name",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(numb)){
        //number is empty
        Toast.makeText(this,"Please Enter your Mobile Number",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    UserInformation userInformation = new UserInformation(name, numb);

    FirebaseUser user =firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

    databaseReference.child(user.getUid()).setValue(userInformation);

    Toast.makeText(this,"Information Saved",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

private void skilldatasave(){

    String skill = accskill.getText().toString().trim();

    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(skill)){
        //skills is empty
        Toast.makeText(this,"Enter Skill to Proceed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    Skilladd skilladds = new Skilladd(skill);

    FirebaseUser user =firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

    databaseReference.child(user.getUid()).setValue(skilladds);

    Toast.makeText(this,"Skills Added Successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

    if (view == accsave){
        userdatasave();
    }

    if (view == accskilladd){
        skilldatasave();
    }

}
}
```

Comment: tried json array?

Comment: No. Will it be helpful if a user wants to add a new skill? Will that new skill get added without replacing the old data?

Comment: u should read first https://www.airpair.com/firebase/posts/structuring-your-firebase-data. I recommend get skills as another json structure for each user ids. so u will have users/userId/{User Model} and skills/userId/{key generated with push()}/{Skills Model}

Comment: Nice idea. It's similar to the sql. How can write it in code?

"user":{
 "name":"xyz"
 "mobile":"12345"
  }
"skills":{
  "userid":""
  "skills":"abc"
  }

Will this work?

Comment: you just need to add new object to existing jsonArray

Comment: i mean how do i do these things with firebase?

Comment: Please check the screenshot that i've uploaded. hope that gives a better understanding of my app and the way things are to be stored in the firebase.